# R: Logistic regression testset prediction error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Anion.gap' not found

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I did a train-test split and obtained `trainset` and `testset` for model building. I need to predict the `trainset` and `testset` error using logistic regression. I managed to build the model and tested successfully on `trainset`:

```
set.seed(22)
nomo=glm(outcome ~ Anion.gap + Lactic.acid + 
           Blood.calcium + Urea.nitrogen + 
           Renal.failure + Diastolic.blood.pressure, 
         family = binomial, data = trainset)

#Test on the trainset
prob.nomo <- predict(nomo,type ='response')

# If probability > threshold, then predict Y = 1, else predict Y = 0
pred.nomo <- ifelse(prob.nomo > threshold, 1, 0)

#Confusion Matrix
cm.nomo.trainset <- table(Trainset.Actual = factor(trainset$outcome),
                          Trainset.Predict = factor(pred.nomo), deparse.level = 2)

cm.nomo.trainset
```

[image]

However, when I tried to test the model on testset, it shows my that the variable object is not found:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Anion.gap' not found

Below is my code for testing on testset:

```
#Test on the testset
prob.nomo.testset <- predict(nomo,type ='response',
                             newdata = testset, probability = TRUE)
```

This is the structure of my trainset and dataset:
[image]

Comment: There is no column named `Anion.gap`in the output of `str(trainset)`. The fit should have thrown an error unless there's an object named `Anion.gap` in the global environment. How did you do the split?

Comment: The screen shot on structure of trainset is only part of it. I have too many variables in my dataset so didn't manage to show all. I did a 70-30 train-test split. str(testset$`Anion gap`)
 num [1:352] 12.3 13.7 14.5 13.8 14 ...

Comment: `predict` expects the new data to have the same columns that were in the fitting data set. Check if `any(names(testset) == "Anion.gap")` returns true.

Comment: > any(names(testset) == "Anion.gap")
[1] FALSE
> any(names(testset) == "Anion gap")
[1] TRUE

Comment: So I'm guessing its due to column names? My dataset has spaces between them so the format is a bit off?

Comment: I tried to change column name of my trainset: colnames(testset)[colnames(testset) == `Anion gap`] <- "Anion.gap".  another another says Error in colnames(testset)[colnames(testset) == `Anion gap`] <- "Anion.gap" : 
  object 'Anion gap' not found

Comment: Maybe `names(testset)[grep("Anion", names(testset))] <- "Anion.gap"`. Or `i<- grep("Anion", names(testset)); names(testset)[i] <- "Anion.gap"`